# Google Fit Rest API: Access Raw Sensor Data

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, rest, google-fit, real-time-data

I want to access raw sensor data (Real-Time Data) with the Google Fit **Rest** API.
This is a link to the Documentation for the normal Google Fit Api for accessing raw sensor data. [Google Fit API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/sensors?hl=cs)

I found no specific documentation for the Google Fit REST API for that special purpose and i'm struggling adapting it to the REST API (POST/GET/PUT..) commands.

Im using Xamarin.Forms with REST API because the provided Fit API's from Microsoft and Google are crap.
I can access stored data and everything works like it should. But i'm not able to figure out how to consume the recording/sensor api.

Can someone help me out or just telling me that it's not possible?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: There is no REST API for accessing the sensors, you need to work with the Fit API to the device directly.

Comment: I already had that thoughts but i never had a prove.. so thank you for for saving a a lot of my lifetime and preventing me from getting mental illness!

Comment: As I understood the documentation, the Rest API never talk to the sensors directly, but to the google webservices which already stored the data.   the Fit API interface directly with the sensors on the device, which allows more real-time interaction.  Only if your app is running on the same device, are you be able to use the Fit API

Comment: @Schwarzie2478 that is correct. The REST API has no notion of where data is coming from (as in, it can't tell if it is from a physical sensor or if you're manually inputting the data, etc), it just takes the data it is sent.